# m2e-wro4j not building after maven clean

Tags: java, eclipse, twitter-bootstrap, maven, wro4j

I'm using the wro4j-maven-plugin v1.7.7 along with m2e-wro4j v1.1.0 eclipse plugin to build my customized bootstrap less theme for my webapp. I will commonly do a Run As->Maven clean, followed by a Run As->Maven install through Eclipse Luna when I make major changes to some of the core classes and want to make sure everything is up-to-date in my local tomcat7.

The problem being, after running the clean, the m2e-wtp/web-resources is cleared which contains my compiled less and js. Then running the install doesn't recreate these because the m2e-wro4j plugin didn't detect any changes. Finally, running the webapp on my local server it ends up with no js or css. If I touch any of the files, it will rebuild them and it works fine.

Is there anyway to force m2e-wro4j to rebuild the resources after a maven clean?

Here is my plugin configuration:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>ro.isdc.wro4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>wro4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${wro4j.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <destinationFolder>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</destinationFolder>
        <cssDestinationFolder>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/styles/</cssDestinationFolder>
        <jsDestinationFolder>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/scripts/</jsDestinationFolder>
        <wroManagerFactory>ro.isdc.wro.maven.plugin.manager.factory.ConfigurableWroManagerFactory</wroManagerFactory>
        <incrementalBuildEnabled>false</incrementalBuildEnabled>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

and my wro.properties:

```
preProcessors=cssImport,semicolonAppender   
postProcessors=lessCss,cssMinJawr,jsMin
```

Comment: This might be related to m2e-wro4j eclipse plugin. The wro4j maven plugin has a  built-in incremental change detection mechanism, which can be enabled by setting incrementalBuildEnabled to true.